# How to store a one-to-one relationship table for fast lookups in Python?

Tags: python, lookup, one-to-one

There is a one-to-one relationship between every two columns of a table, say `Ci <--> Cj`.

How do I store such a table for fast lookups? I'll express myself clearly with the following code snippet.

```
C1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
C2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
C3 = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']

# lookup, Ci --> Cj
idx = Ci.index(val)
corresponding_val = Cj[idx]
```

Dict would be a good choice. Take a table with only two columns as an example, store the table as a dict, say `d[C1] = C2`. It takes `O(1)` from `C1` to `C2`. But from `C2` to `C1`, it will take longer.

Comment: What about having two dicts, one for each way? Or a dict that has each relationship twice, once each way?

Comment: @ddsnowboard, it works for two columns. But for *n* columns, we need *n*(n-1)* dicts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need a quick lookup of a key in any of C1,C2,C3 then three dicts. The value of each is a 3-tuple.

```
all = zip( C1, C2, C3)
d1,d2,d3 = {},{},{}
for v in all:
   d1[ v[0]], d2[v[1]], d3[v[2]] = v,v,v
```

Usage:

```
>>> d3['three']
(3, 'c', 'three')
>>> d1[1]
(1, 'a', 'one')
>>> d2['a']
(1, 'a', 'one')
```

This is three indexes accessing just one set of tuple data, so it's about as efficient as it could be given that you need one hash index for each fast lookup.

```
assert d1[1] is d2['a'] and d1[1] is d3['one']
```

Only one dict is needed for each column because what is accessed is the whole row. However, there is an assumption that there are no duplicate values in any column. If there may be duplicates then each retrieved value needs to be a list of row tuples, not simply the one and only row tuple. If you need this it is not a lot harder to set up:

```
C2=['odd','even','odd','even']
...
for v in all:
    d1.setdefault(v[0],[]).append(v)
    d2.setdefault(v[1],[]).append(v)
    d3.setdefault(v[2],[]).append(v)   

>>> d2
{'even': [(2, 'even', 'two'), (4, 'even', 'four')], 'odd': [(1, 'odd',  'one'), (3, 'odd', 'three')]}
```

Comment: It could be useful to merge all of the keys into one dictionary.  Change the assignment to `d[v[0]], d[v[1]], d[v[2]] = v`.  In this case, you only need to do `d[C1[i]]` or `d[C2[i]]` or `d[C3[i]]`.

Comment: @John Carpenter Yes, that'll work as long as there are no duplicated values in the merger of all the columns. If there are, then it still works if you use `setdefault` to build a list, and having retrieved all matching rows check to see if the match was on the correct column or not.

Answer (score 1):

What about to zip all columns in a unique list. Kind of:

```
D = zip(C1, C2, C3,...)
```

In this way you can loop over the first element of D and returns the others that you need, using a comprehesion list.

Comment: "Fast lookup" means something better than linear search: a hash table, which is what a dict provides. Search is  O(N). Hash table is O(1) or at worst for large N, O( ln N).

Comment: Yep @nigel222. I forgot it, my fault.
Indeed, using hash always be better... So, what could be the acceptable solution without using hash? It uses a algorythm for ordering the list (binary tree sort,...), then you can use another algorythm for searching the results,... Your cost could be more than acceptable if you have to do several searches... O(n log n) (once) and O(log n).

Comment: If you are using Python and everything fits in memory, just use a dict and rely on the folks that develop Python having chosen good hashing algorithms and internal data structures. Without Python ... well I once used a 16-bit hash value to select from one of 64K  lists. Most of the hash values addressed a single-element list, because there were about 40,000 things to index. Only reason I had to roll my own, was it was an ancient Fortran code that was being used harder than its original programmers ever expected. In general, there's a library code already!

Comment: Thanks for replying me @nigel222. I used a few of those algorythms when I was programming C++ over Linux shell (college´s age). Yep, it sounds logical, Python developers knows what they are doing :).
Regards mate.